# Angular Promise, why am I getting 'then' of undefined in this instance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, angular-promise

I have a function in my chartDirective which makes a call to a function in a service to GET data, format that data then call another function from my chartDirective:

```
function chartTicker(ticker, disabled) {
    disabled = disabled || false;
    var defer = $q.defer();

    // Clear out previous chart:
    d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();
    document.getElementById('chart').innerHTML = "";
    chart     = {},
    chartData = [];

    // Get and format data for chart:
    document.getElementById('chart').innerHTML = "<svg></svg>";
    var timeInHours = TimeSpanFactory.getTimeHours();

    var promise = FormatChartDataFactory.getData(ticker, timeInHours).then(function() {
        defer.resolve();
        return defer.promise;
    });
}
```

However I am getting the following error on the following line:
[image]

```
var promise = FormatChartDataFactory.getData(ticker, timeInHours).then(function() {
```

---

Here is my `FormatChartDataFactory.getData` function:

```
function getData(ticker, limit) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    chartObj.chartData = [{}];
    var limit_range = '';

    if (limit > 0) {
        limit_range = '?limit=' + limit;
    }

    getTickerPrice(ticker, limit_range).then(function() {
        defer.resolve();
        return defer.promise;
    });

    // GET Ticker data and return chartObj into drawChart:
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function getTickerPrice(ticker, limit_range) {
        return ApiFactory.getTickerQuotes(ticker.ticker, limit_range)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if (data.status === 'Success') {
                // ....
```

Here is the [**link to my full FormatChartDataFactory gist file**](https://gist.github.com/leongaban/14fae55136be29c4d782).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promise should be return from code directly, it shouldn't be return from the `.then` callback of it. In short you have not returned promise from function and you are looking for `.then` method there, which results into an error.

**Code**

```
//1st place
var promise = FormatChartDataFactory.getData(ticker, timeInHours).then(function() {
    defer.resolve();
});
return defer.promise;

//2nd place
getTickerPrice(ticker, limit_range).then(function() {
    defer.resolve();
});
return defer.promise;
```

Comment: Lol that was it! This was the fastest answer in history :)

Comment: @LeonGaban Glad to help you ..Thanks :)